# In a variable thats an array, how do you scan for each array index?

Tags: c

Let's say there is a variable that is letters[MAX], and I want to scan for each array index like letters[1], letters[2], etc. How is this done?

I tried doing a for loop something like

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
   printf ("Letter: ");
   scanf ("%d", &letters[i]);
}
```

but this does not work properly. I mean it works, but it'll keep scanning until I reach whatever the MAX is (which is 100 in my program) and I tried putting it in a do while loop while (letters != 0) but it is outside of the for loop and doesn't end the loop when I enter 0.

So what I'm trying to do is assign a value to each array variable (letters[i]) by `scanf`'ing user input and ending the loop when 0 is entered, but the code I've tried does not work.

Comment: you want the address of letter[] or the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can add

```
if(letters[i]=='0')
   break;
```

to the end of your for loop. This way it checks to see if the letter you just entered was a 0 character (hence the single quotes).

You end up with

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
   printf ("Letter: ");
   scanf ("%d", &letters[i]);
   if(letters[i]=='0')
      break;
}
```

Comment: hey i've run into another problem!

I added 2 more array variables to my for loop so it looks like the code you gave me with the if statement added only with 2 more printf / scanf lines, and it is still the same if statement (if letters==0) but instead of letters ending the program when 0 is entered, it is the 3rd array variable that ends the program if 0 is entered even though letters is in the if statement!...EDIT: fixed it, i just added the if statement after the first scanf and put the other 2 below it and it fixed!

Comment: @user1808190 If you have a new question that's unrelated, it'd probably be better to finish this one and ask a new question. Either way, best to post code chunks in questions/answers, not comments. Also, accept the answers people give to you - other people have answered your other questions to your liking, so you should hit the checkmark for their answer.